# Who kept the Cumaean Sybil in a jar (ampulla)?

Tags: greek, roman, trojan-war, apollo, oracle

I have [previously asked a question](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/3237/is-the-cumaean-sybil-known-by-any-other-name) about the Virgin of Cumae, or the Cumaean Sybil, so the info will, for the most part, just be a memorize and type deal.

The Virgin of Cumae was a priestess with the gift of prophecy. She would write her prophecies on oak leaves an arrange them. But, when the wind blew them out of order, she did not put them back together.

One day, Apollo came down to declare his love and offered her a gift, in exchange for her virginity. She picked up a pile of sand and asked for the years of the gains of sand she held. Apollo complied, but later, the Cumaean Sybil repealed her promise and kept her virginity.

She kept the long life and the power of prophecy, for it was he own. But, Apollo did nothing to keep her beautiful throughout her long life. Her body withered and eventually (somewhere down the line of the tapestry) made her way to the Underworld, still living.

When Troy was sacked, Aeneas escaped. On his journey, he met the Cumaean Sybil and delivered her back to the world of the living.

She is said to have lived a thousand years. As she withered, she became so small, she was eventually kept in a jar (an ampulla jar) until only her voice remained.

Who kept her in the ampulla?